# PHP simple html dom file_get_html how to extract/break after div

Tags: php, dom

I am trying to fetch something through `file_get_html` everything seems fine but stuck on one part, i am using `foreach` function to extract a `<li>` and the problem is it is extracting all the li under that specific div or ul please read the following code.

Trying to extract from these lines

```
<ul class="x-name y-name">
<li>example 1</li>
<li>example 2</li>
<li>example 3</li>
</ul>
```

using

```
foreach($html->find("div#master") as $e){
        foreach ($e->find("otherobject]") as $es){
        $val["myuse-".strip_tags($es)] = "";
            foreach($e->find("ul[class='x-name b-name'] li") as $elist){
            $val["myuse-".strip_tags($es)] .= "<li>".strip_tags($elist->innertext)."</li>";

            }
        }
}
```

The problem is its not returning after completion of 3 `<li>` it is    continuing drilling down to all the same name `<li>` What I want it to    stop after the `<li>` numbers are complete and return to the previous    `foreach` and when the next name is selected then it will search for    next ul li.

Comment: Should the base of the inner `foreach($e->find("ul[cl...` be `$es`? (i.e. `foreach($es->find`

Comment: can you please shed some more light ?

Comment: Do you have a fuller example of the code which shows a sample HTML, the code which loads this and then I may be able to reproduce the issue.